# Explanation of speed difference in two implementations of queue

Tags: scala, performance

I have the following code that implements a queue. One using a linked list and one using two stacks (with expensive dequeue operation) which is in turn also implemented using a linked list.

I'm confused as to why the enqueue operation on the stack implementation is faster even though they both use the same underlying data structure (linked list). My code is below (operations not necessary to reproduce the behavior are not show).

```
case class Node[T](data: T, var next: Node[T])

class StackList[T] {

  private var top: Node[T] = _

  private var total: Int = 0

  def push(item: T): Unit = {
    val o = top
    val n = Node(item, o)
    total = total + 1
    top = n
  }
}

class QueueStackDq[T] extends Queue[T] {

  val in = new StackList[T]

  val out = new StackList[T]

  private var total: Int = 0

  /**
    * Add an element to the queue's tail
    */
  def enqueue(item: T): Unit = {
    total = total + 1
    in.push(item)
  }
}



class QueueList[T] extends Queue[T] {

  private var tail: Node[T] = _

  private var head: Node[T] = _

  private var total: Int = 0


  /**
    * Add an element to the queue's tail
    */
  def enqueue(item: T): Unit = {
    val n = Node(item, null) // Create new node
    if (total == 0) {
      head = n
      tail = n
    }
    total += 1
    tail.next = n
    tail = n
  }
}
```

Testing the enqueue operation with 1,000,000 records shows that the linked list implementation runs in 0.01 seconds while the stack implementation runs in 0.00026 seconds! That's a significant difference in time!

Comment: Benchmarking code performance is an artform. For a variety of reasons (JVM JIT performance, garbage collection cycles, etc.) run-speeds can vary significantly. To get accurate benchmarks, I recommend [_ScalaMeter_](https://scalameter.github.io/). BTW, why do you track `total` in `QueueStackDq[T]` when `StackList[T]` does also? Also, I think you have a bug in `QueueList[T].enqueue` - if `total` is 0, `tail.next` end up as `tail` instead of `null`.

Comment: `null` is a dangerous hang-over from Java; use `Option[Node[T]]` for the `next` field

Comment: You should read and understand the whole thread at https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mechanical-sympathy/m4opvy4xq3U/h-n4eNw2SmoJ before you write any benchmarks. (While this thread is specifically about JVM benchmarking, it applies equally to any modern high-performance execution engine). If you read it and *don't* understand it (like I do), you should really refrain from writing benchmarks (or at least from placing any value into their results).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've created a [*ScalaMeter*](http://scalameter.github.io/)-based benchmark for this example problem and [placed it on *GitHub*](https://github.com/MichaelJAllen/listperf).

On my machine, I get benchmarks as follows (timings in milliseconds) for your original program (tagged V1.0):

```
QueueStackDq: 5.757413
QueueList:    5.699053
```

After removing redundancies and fixing the bug as referred to in my comment, the benchmarks become (tagged V2.0):

```
QueueStackDq: 5.317035
QueueList:    5.670139
```

Either way, there's not a huge difference between the two implementations (and these results may not be statistically significant, as the sample size for the benchmarks isn't large).

So to answer your question, it turns out that the stack implementation isn't orders of magnitude faster after all. Your initial intuition that the two approaches should be similar, because they use similar data structures, was correct.

BTW, using `null` and *mutable* variables & collections is frowned upon in *Scala*. A functional version that doesn't use either would be much easier to reason about.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Aware that scala frowns upon the use of mutable types (referential transparency) but writing these programs simply as exercises in data structures & algorithms.

Comment: "these results may not be statistically significant" -- for future reference, if you use JMH for benchmarking, it outputs stats info including statistical significance figures.

Answer (score 1):

The difference in the two `enqueue` methods is just that one has indirection via the `StackList.push` method and one does not (as if you had inlined that method).

Assuming that you did the benchmarking correctly (and you have not shown that code here), then it seems that you are measuring the difference between making that method call and inlining that method.

If you had called the method often enough, I would expect the JVM to inline the method for you, but it is difficult to explain why it has not without seeing your benchmark code. I would recommend ScalaMeter or JMH for micro benchmarks.

I would also caution you that this kind of micro benchmark is rarely useful or informative. Do you actually have a production system where the difference between these two bits of code will be significant? In almost every case, this kind of tiny performance difference will be swamped by other factors like network performance or larger-scale architectural choices.

Comment: Just trying to teach myself data structures. No production system in place here. But thanks for the comment.